# How do I get YouTube community posts older than 200

Tags: youtube-api

It seems in YouTube that if a user uploads more than 200 community posts, the new ones trump the last ones. They seem to still exist but YouTube seems to only give back the first 200 posts.
Is there any way of getting those old posts?

Edit: "Please provide a channel having this issue"
All channels with more than 200 posts have this issue.
I haven't seen anything about this in the api or any commentary by YouTube, but it is a bother if you want to watch older posts; they still exist I think, you just can't access to them cause YouTube doesn't generate the response.
https://www.youtube.com/@NatGeo/community

Comment: Please provide a channel having this issue.

Comment: Already done, it happens to all channels, for example the national geographic channel.

Comment: [I confirm your issue](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2571341) but can't do anything as it's on YouTube side. Note that you can verify that *older posts [...] still exist* by keeping the URL of your first community post and then post 200 more community posts. Don't hesitate to notice us back the result of this experiment if you do it.

Comment: Yes, the posts still exist. For example at the moment in the national geographic channel this is the community post number 201 https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpVm7bg6pXKo1Pr6k5kxG9A/community?lb=Ugkx-XFWapVxVo-pR8WTPlLOtV9XQaNJlhSz. They have added a new post, so now you can't see this post unless you have a direct link, cause YouTube stops loading posts at 200.

Comment: [I tried a lower-level approach](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/257) but I am currently technically unaware to investigate it completely.